# How do I dynamically create an html table given only a table name in entity framework?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My code is more like creating an engine that when passed a table name variable, will construct the table dynamically. This is the code I'm already working on. In my controller,

```
    public ActionResult ViewTable(string tablename)
    {
        ScsContext context = new ScsContext();
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();

        var html = "<table><thead><tr>";

        switch(tablename)
        {
            case "table1":

                columnNames = typeof(table1).GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name).ToList();

                foreach(var c in columnNames)
                {
                    html += "<td>" + c.ToString() + "</td>";
                }

                html += "</tr></thead><tbody>";

                var rows = from c in context.table1.ToList()
                           select c;
                foreach(var c in rows)
                {
                    foreach(var p in c.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        foreach(var s in columnNames)
                        {
                            if(p.Name == s.ToString())
                            {
                                // How do I get the value here?
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                break;

            // more case statements here based on table names
            default:
                break;
        }


        // return empty for now
        return new EmptyResult();

    }
```

I was able to loop the names of my columns in my entities, as above, and now constructing my html table based on those values.. but when I need to get the value now, I'm stucked. How do I get the value from my properties above to construct my html table based on table name variable?

And since I have more hundred tables the user want rendered, is there a simpler and more efficient way to do this?

Thanks very much,

Comment: it's really bad practice to do it like you do in Controller. It's better to create your table on View (With strongly typed Razor Views) and to get table headers use `DataAnnotation` `[Name]` above your collection properties. That's one of MVC ways solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I will be spending a couple more days for every view that I will make, considering that the user want to view the hundred master tables.. all user want is a menu for every master table that he can click so he can view it

Comment: If you are worried you will be re-creating this many times then create a partial view.

Comment: @Cal279 i think OP worried about fact that he should create table for each entity that he use. But i suppose it's better to create `HtmlHelper` for this case. It won't be easy but you can search for already exist solutions and it will also be MVC approach for this situation.